# How do I plot multi case function in wolfram or geogebra?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, wolfram-alpha

How do I plot the following multi case function in wolfram or geogebra?

$$
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1, &\text{if }x \text{ is an integer},
\\ 0, &\text{if }x \text{ is not an integer}.
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

The graph would be dots and underscores?

Comment: Here's a piecewise defined function (but the graph isn't what you want -- I'd like to know how to do that as well): "Piecewise[{{1, x == Floor[x]}}, 0]" Link:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Piecewise[{{1%2C+x+%3D%3D+Floor[x]}}%2C+0]

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite do that with a nice picture, but [the reverse](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceiling%28x%29-floor%28x%29) works more or less with [`ceiling(x)-floor(x)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceiling%28x%29-floor%28x%29) and looks like

[image]

Comment: I am amused that Alpha claims a numercal root at $x=1.1$

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Boole%5BNot%5BIntegerQ%5Bx%5D%5D%5D+for+x+from+-7+to+7) is supposed to be equivalent, but somehow the expected gaps don't show up...